# Mix 2 strings that do not have the same length?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to mix two strings like this:

```cs
string a1 = "123456";
string a2 = "DFEG";

var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(a1[i]);
    builder.Append(a2[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

I want the output to be "**1D2F3E4G56**".

It works if both strings are the same lengths, but not if they're different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int maxIndex = a1.Length > a2.Length ? a1.Length : a2.Length;
 for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
 {
   if(a1.Length > i)
     builder.Append(a1[i]);
            
   if(a2.Length > i)
     builder.Append(a2[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The array access here will result in out of bounds exception

Use [Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=net-6.0) to attempt accessing the array at that index, or have it use that type's default value if said index is out of bounds

Since these are of the string type, the default value will be `""` or `string.empty` which is perfectly acceptable for your situation as it won't alter the string you want to return

```
 builder.Append(a1.ElementAtOrDefault(i));
 builder.Append(b1.ElementAtOrDefault(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Good luck

```
string a1 = "123456";
string a2 = "DFEGfgg";

MixStrings(a1,a2);

public void MixStrings(string a, string b)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("");
    for (int i = 0; i < (a.Length > b.Length ? a.Length : b.Length); i++)
    {
        builder.Append(a.Length>i?a[i]:"");
        builder.Append(b.Length>i?b[i]:"");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```